# log out command for Lubuntu desktop

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, lxqt, lxsession

I know for gnome session the command looks something like this:
`gnome-session-quit`

What is the equivalent for an Lxqt (Ubuntu with Lxqt and openbox WM) desktop session ?

Comment: I don't use LXQt, but do the answer below works for you ?

Comment: @Emmet , just  tested and yeah seems to be working. So when you hit that `lxqt-leave` , a menu pops up with option to logout , shutdown,reboot and all that stuff. So it's pretty cool for someone like me who is too lethargic to bring up the menu.lol

Comment: Do you want the command that logs you out, straight to login menu ?

Comment: @Emmet yeah, if you know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several binaries you can download to control different settings in LXQt:

`lxqt-leave`

deals with interrupting or terminating sessions. It comes with several options expressing the action they trigger, e. g.

`--leave`
 `--hibernate`
`--shutdown`
`--reboot`

`lxqt-session`

This binary is launched right at the beginning of LXQt sessions and in turn is responsible for launching and monitoring all other components constituting the sessions.

`lxqt-config`

is another binary which will give you the "Configuration Center" which is a GUI that has several options to choose from that allow you to control the appearance as well as other configurations. One of them being

[lxqt-globalkeys](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-globalkeys)

`lxqt-globalkeysd`

can be adjusted from section "Basic Settings" in configuration dialogue [LXQt Session Settings](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-session#overview) of [lxqt-session](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-session).

`lxqt-config-globalkeyshortcuts`

which is used to customize shortcuts can be opened from the panel's main menu - Preferences - LXQt Settings - Shortcut Keys and is provided by the [Configuration Center](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-config#configuration-center) of [lxqt-config](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-config) as well.

All this info and more can be found at the LXQt GitHub page or their official web-page:
[LXQt(github)](https://github.com/lxqt?page=2)
[LXQt(.org)](https://lxqt.org/)